# Base64 decode encode, getting different data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, go, base64

I am developing an amazon s3 app with golang. I'm having some trouble and confused.

From the [aws s3 upload example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) the first step uses Base64 encoded:

```
{ "expiration": "2013-08-06T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"bucket": "examplebucket"},
    ["starts-with", "$key", "user/user1/"],
    {"acl": "public-read"},
    {"success_action_redirect": "http://acl6.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html"},
    ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
    {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
    ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],

    {"x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130806/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"},
    {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
    {"x-amz-date": "20130806T000000Z" }
  ]
}
```

I'm supposed to get:

```
eyAiZXhwaXJhdGlvbiI6ICIyMDEzLTA4LTA3VDEyOjAwOjAwLjAwMFoiLA0KICAiY29uZGl0aW9ucyI6IFsNCiAgICB7ImJ1Y2tldCI6ICJleGFtcGxlYnVja2V0In0sDQogICAgWyJzdGFydHMtd2l0aCIsICIka2V5IiwgInVzZXIvdXNlcjEvIl0sDQogICAgeyJhY2wiOiAicHVibGljLXJlYWQifSwNCiAgICB7InN1Y2Nlc3NfYWN0aW9uX3JlZGlyZWN0IjogImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlYnVja2V0LnMzLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20vc3VjY2Vzc2Z1bF91cGxvYWQuaHRtbCJ9LA0KICAgIFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCAiJENvbnRlbnQtVHlwZSIsICJpbWFnZS8iXSwNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LW1ldGEtdXVpZCI6ICIxNDM2NTEyMzY1MTI3NCJ9LA0KICAgIFsic3RhcnRzLXdpdGgiLCAiJHgtYW16LW1ldGEtdGFnIiwgIiJdLA0KDQogICAgeyJ4LWFtei1jcmVkZW50aWFsIjogIkFLSUFJT1NGT0ROTjdFWEFNUExFLzIwMTMwODA2L3VzLWVhc3QtMS9zMy9hd3M0X3JlcXVlc3QifSwNCiAgICB7IngtYW16LWFsZ29yaXRobSI6ICJBV1M0LUhNQUMtU0hBMjU2In0sDQogICAgeyJ4LWFtei1kYXRlIjogIjIwMTMwODA2VDAwMDAwMFoiIH0NCiAgXQ0KfQ==
```

However, I get a different result:

```
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
```

Why am I getting a different result then expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you know base64 can be decoded as well as encoded? It is not an encryption algorithm, it is a codification. There are many base64 encoding/decoding online services.

If you decode it, you can see the amazon provided one has this value:

`action_redirect: http://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/successful_upload.html`

`expiration` also differs. They probably didn't update the encoded string after changing the json example.

Comment: it's indeed like this,the amazon's example is old or wrong.thank you very much!